# How to use WooCommerce Deposits - Partial Payments Plugin in the cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system, payment, cart

I’m using “WooCommerce Deposits - Partial Payments Plugin” in my website.

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-deposits-partial-payments-plugin/9249233

I’ve set it up to provide the user ability to pay a deposit or pay the full amount in product details page and it’s working fine.
But I’m planning to use it in the cart page with respect to each product added in the cart.

The plugin is not providing any such option. Is it possible to achieve this with this plugin?

Please suggest.

Attached is the screenshot of current cart page and desired cart page.

[Current & desired cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taqys.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this on cart page for individual product. For display deposit function on cart page you need to do custom code on cart page.

Comment: Thanks Mohod,I need to do it by using the same plugin. Also can you please let me know a logic about how to do it?

Comment: You need to do this kind of code on cart page:
 $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);
if ($product && isset($product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit === 'yes'){
      // load deposit function here
}
      {

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Comment: I've added custom code in teh plugin; mostly javascript to get it worked.